# Qt WebEngine on Windows with Visual Studio 2017 incognito mode

Tags: windows, visual-studio, qt, webengine

I managed to create VS app to load a web page with qt WebEngine. Now I would like to use incognito mode but I cant figure out how to translate the qt documentation to VS?

https://doc.qt.io/QT-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-simplebrowser-example.html

How would I define profiles in VS?

Comment: ***I cant figure out how to translate the qt documentation to VS?*** I am confused at your question. The code should be the exact same in Qt-Creator as it is when using Visual Studio as the IDE. The configuration of the project may be different or the same depending on how you are using the Qt framework in Visual Studio 2017. I use CMake since 2008 at work to develop my Qt based applications on several different versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: The documentation for defining a profile is here: [https://doc.qt.io/QT-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-simplebrowser-example.html#implementing-private-browsing](https://doc.qt.io/QT-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-simplebrowser-example.html#implementing-private-browsing) I don't see any reason the code would be different if you were using Visual Studio 2017 or Qt creator.

Comment: The problem is that I dont have a browser window. I used the Qt designer and that created two WebEngineViews. So I dont have a browser or browser window instance where I could attach the profile. I would like the two WebEngineViews to be private browser instances.